# Android application closes on click

Tags: android, android-activity

I do my android app , but I have a bug I don't know how to fix it.
My code is below :

This is my Main Activity :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private ImageView imgHot;

public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE="com.cuonglm.KhoHinh.MESSAGE";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imgHot=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageViewHot);


    imgHot.setOnClickListener(toContentHot);

}
View.OnClickListener toContentHot=new View.OnClickListener() {  

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent content=new Intent(MainActivity.this,ContentActivity.class);
        String signal="1";
        content.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE,signal);
        startActivity(content);         
    }
};
```

And this is my second Activity :

```
public class ContentActivity extends Activity {
private TextView viewMessage;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent content=getIntent();
    String messageReceive=content.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    viewMessage=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.content_receive);
    viewMessage.setText(messageReceive);        

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_content);
}
```

I want to click on the image on the Main Activity , string "1" or number "1" will send to the Second Activity via Intent and view on the TextView.

But my app will be close "Unfortunately..."

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Change to

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_content);
viewMessage=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.content_receive);
viewMessage.setText(messageReceive);
```

In your `ContentActivity`

`findViewById` looks for a view with the id for the current infalted layout. SO you need to set the content of your layout to the activity first and then initialize your views.

You are probably gettting `NullPointerException` coz your initialization fails.

Comment: Yes. It was really a close call. All three of us racing to be the first one to answer. Anyway, thanks for the up. Favour returned. :)

Comment: I do not understand your solution yet, this code is not change compare to my code ? Thanks

Comment: @CuongLe the change is you need to have this `setContentView(R.layout.activity_content)` before `findViewById`. ANd what is that you still don't understand . I even explained why in my post

Answer (score 3):

You need to call `setContentView()` in your second `Activity` before trying to access any of the `Views` in that `layout`. Change it to

```
   public class ContentActivity extends Activity {

   private TextView viewMessage;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_content);
      Intent content=getIntent();
      String messageReceive=content.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

      viewMessage=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.content_receive);
      viewMessage.setText(messageReceive);        
  }
```

If this doesn't fix your problem then please post your logcat so we can see the error. Also always post logcat in the future when your app crashes. They aren't always this easy to see.

Also, I'm not sure you understand how `putExtra()` works. It is a `key, value` pair so when you put `EXTRA_MESSAGE` as the `key` then that is what you would use to retrieve the value added in the second param. So the way you are doing it may work if the `Activity` gets destroyed but it looks really strange to me and probably not realy safe or efficient. I would change it to something like

```
content.putExtra("message",signal);
```

in your first `Activity` then get it with

```
String messageReceive = content.getStringExtra("message");
```

in your second `Activity`

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the layout before trying to reference the Views associated with it.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent content=getIntent();
    String messageReceive=content.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_content);

    viewMessage=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.content_receive);
    viewMessage.setText(messageReceive);        

}
```

Comment: Glad to be of help! :)